# RxJS: Subject for only storing and notifying latest message

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am looking for a Subject which combines the functionalities of the `ReplaySubject` with the ones of a `BehaviourSubject`. It should:

- have no initial value (unlike the `BehaviourSubject` but like the `ReplaySubject`)
- only send events to subscribers for the latest change (unlike the `ReplaySubject` but like the `BehaviourSubject`)

Your explaination does not need to be version-specific as I am not bound to a specfic one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be looking for `ReplaySubject(1)`.

Passing a value of `1` will just store the **most recent** value, like a `BehaviourSubject`, but still no initial value.